# Listing next batch of objects from AmazonS3 client after deleting objects from previous object listing

Tags: amazon-s3

Does this work?

1. Get object listing for a list request on a bucket.
2. Realize that object listing is truncated.
3. Delete keys belonging to this object listing.
4. Fetch next batch of objects using current object listing.

Note that state of the s3 bucket is changing between the two uses of the first object listing in steps 2 and 4 i.e. objects from previous listing no longer exist in the bucket. Is this approach correct?

Can this be used as a way to delete objects from a bucket?

Answer (score 2):

If at step 4 you specify the `marker` from the previous listing (the key to start from) you shouldn't have any problems.

But if at step 4 you restart the listing from the first key in the bucket (without specifying the `marker`), you will have problems because of S3's eventual consistency model (the list operation might return keys that have been deleted).